# "Suffer from" use for non human contexts

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it normal to use "suffer from" for subjects other than humans? For example is it acceptable to say: "this old building suffer from irregular electricity"

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Figurative and metaphorical speech is commonplace in English.

Comment: Certainly it would not be at all unusual in the US to hear someone says that a building is "suffering from neglect".  "Suffering from irregular electricity", on the other hand, is a little "odd".  I haven't thought through a bunch of examples, but I'm guessing that to "suffer", an inanimate object needs to be the subject of neglect, abuse, overuse, etc -- things that are the result of human interaction (or the lack thereof).

Comment: It would certainly be normal to use "suffer from" in a bit of fiction featuring anthropomorphism, say in stories from the Thomas the Tank (R) series, where the various characters are portrayed as having a variety of human emotions, and other characteristics. The Thomas stories are by no means the only ones; there are countless other examples.

Comment: It should be "this old building sufferS from irregular electricity".

Comment: Or 'these old buildings suffer'.

Answer (score 1):

People often connect *suffer* with human privation, in part perhaps because of its longtime pairing with *pain* in the legal phrase "pain and suffering." The first meaning that *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) reports for *suffer* as a transitive verb is

> to submit to or be forced to endure {*suffer* martyrdom}

and the second and third definitions it gives for *suffer* as an intransitive verb are

> **2 :** to sustain loss or damage **3 :** to be subject to disability or handicap

Nothing in the plain terms of these definition requires the sufferer to be human or, indeed, alive at all. The emphasis is on enduring something damaging or otherwise undesirable, not on feeling pain or unpleasant emotions. It follows that "The lunar landscape has suffered numerous impacts from meteorites" and "The election suffered from various vote-counting irregularities," and "This old building suffers from irregular electricity" use *suffer* in well-established ways.

Comment: TL;DR, that's a yes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more in keeping with the personification of the building in question to say that the *plumbing* was irregular. The electricity would more likely suffer epileptic fits.